# Avoid queuing spark microbatches

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have created spark application which takes the input data from Apache flume. I set my spark batch interval to 4 minutes, so that spark will process data after every 4 minutes. But I am having some expensive spark batches which takes considerable amount of time (say 30 minutes), so during this time approximately 7 spark batches will be pending in queue and it will start processing one by one once expensive batch execution is completed. By this way my spark remains busy maximum time. So how I can avoid this queuing? If my spark batch is executing and if its take more than 4 minutes, I don't want to add next spark batch in queue.

I am initiating spark as below

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, 240000)// 240000 equals to 4 minutes
```

Comment: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/spark-streaming/spark-streaming-backpressure.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use locking mechanism for it. You need to maintain single row data  for lock at Scheduler end. So when your spark job will trigger after 4 min, it will first check that file/db table and if it return lock `True` then it will `terminate` by doing nothing.

I have also used same approach in my spark job which get trigger in every **3 mins**. So I maintained on *ElasticSearch* Index where I keep single records with data like `application id, start and End time, spark Job Name, Status, Lock`. So when Spark job trigger it first check that index if lock is `False` then it `overwrite` that row/records with `True` with other details and start running otherwise  if Lock is `True` then it stop executing by logging one message *that the application id with spark job name was running*. After 3 mins new Spark job re-trigger and it check all it again. 
When spark job get `finish`, it change the lock to `False` so that next job can be run. I have also handle this in case of job failure so when Job get fail by any reason, it will mark lock as `False` so that next trigger can run without any issue.

There might be required to change few thing at your end as per requirement.

Comment: My spark batches are running sequentially one after the other. So i am not sure how to add locking?

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas that might help or at least give you some insights:

1. If Spark Streaming's backpressure mechanism (or rate limiter for versions < 1.5) doesn't help as suggested in the comments, try changing your push to a pull-based model. This way you'll have more control over your sink and can potentially drop events as you wish.
2. If you are using YARN (regardless of push/pull model), you might be able to configure/reduce the maximum amount of running + pending applications: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html

> Maximum number of applications in the system which can be concurrently active both running and pending. Limits on each queue are directly proportional to their queue capacities and user limits. This is a hard limit and any applications submitted when this limit is reached will be rejected. Default is `10000`. This can be set for all queues with `yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-applications` and can also be overridden on a per queue basis by setting `yarn.scheduler.capacity.<queue-path>.maximum-applications`. Integer value expected.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Agree with what @Fabio said. In this cases options like re-thinking the streaming flow and processing flow helps.